# non-zero exit status 1 error in a R based pipeline

Tags: r

I am running a R based pipeline but getting this error:

```
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 248 of /scratch/1885336/tmpeoay0cuf:
Command 'set -euo pipefail;  Rscript --vanilla /hpc/diaggen/users/.snakemake/scripts/tmp3dq92oqa.wBRender.R' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/scratch/1885336/tmpeoay0cuf", line 248, in __rule_AberrantSplicing_pipeline_FRASER_Summary_R
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
```

I have installed all the required packages and double-checked if they are installed completely but did not manage to fix it.
Does any one know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Care to share some relevant code?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.